# Position error message with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following HTML.  The label is inserted by the jQuery validation plugin, and I don't think I could position it anywhere but directly following the input.  I could easily add a tag around the "Invite Contact" if necessary.

How could I use CSS or the API to position the label inline and after the "Invite Contact" text?

```
<p id="invite">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" name="invite" class="error">
    <label id="invite-error" class="error" for="invite">Email is required if you wish to invite.</label>
    Invite Contact
</p>
```

Comment: jquery-validate has several options related to where it puts the message. You can provide your own DIVs and uses these options to tell it to use it.

Comment: @Barmar  Thank you Barmar.  I was unaware and will check it out.  I am not certain this will be an option for me, however.  I put together a PHP script which takes JSON and both uses it to create client side rules/messages as well as serverside final validation.  I am sure it could be modified, but it won't be easy. Think this could be accomplished just with CSS?

Comment: Don't use CSS when you could just create the correct DOM markup in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CSS when you could just create the proper DOM markup in the first place.

Use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) that is provided by the jQuery Validate plugin to override the default message placement.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element); // <- default, change this to whatever you need
    }
});
```

**Quote OP**:

> *"I could easily add a tag around the "Invite Contact" if necessary."*

I surrounded your `"Invite Contact"` text with `<span>` tags and used this function in the demo...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).next());
}
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8pawpsht/**

---

Can be restricted to a certain element by using a conditional...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if ($(element).attr('id') == 'foo') {
        error.insertAfter($(element).next());
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element); // <- default
    }
}
```

**DEMO 2: http://jsfiddle.net/8pawpsht/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8pawpsht/2/**

Comment: If I had multiple inputs in the form, but just wanted one to be placed different than the default, would I just use something like: `errorPlacement: function (error, element) {var $e=$(element);   error.insertAfter($e.attr('id')=='foo'?$e.next():$e); }`?

Comment: @user1032531, YES, you can use a conditional to restrict to certain elements.  http://jsfiddle.net/8pawpsht/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could float the checkbox right, and the label left.  You could add a div inside of invite, to control this.

HTML

```
<p id="invite">
<span class="wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" name="invite" class="error">
<label id="invite-error" class="error" for="invite">Email is required if you wish to invite.</label>
</span>
<strong>Invite Contact</strong>
</p>
```

CSS

```
#invite {
display:block;
width:100%;
height:250px;
background:#d7d7d7;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
background:white;
display:block;
border:2px solid #333;
height:20px;
width: 275px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.error {
float:right;
}
#invite-error {
float:left;
}
```

For reference, check out my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEVveG)